Yellowbrick DB DateTime to Date type-casting not showing only date format (YYYY-MM-DD)
I'm working in YelloBrick DB. I want to extract only Date value from DateTime value column.
In this scenario generally we use query: CAST([dateTime_Value] as DATE)
So, I'm type-casting from DateTime (timestamp) format to Date format, it's showing Date format along with extra time format (12:00:00).
This is my YelloBrick Code: (check the RED BOX area)

So, I convert dateTime column data to String (Varchar/TEXT) format and then I use Regular-Expression(or String function will work) to Replace/Match the specific area to extract date-only part: YYYY-MM-DD. (Green BOX area of above image).
I already worked in MySQL & PostgresSQL and there this method is working fine.

My question is,
Is there any simple way to do extract date-only format ?
I don't want to use Regex or String function here . . .

EOD I found a meaningful solution:
select CAST(CAST(NOW() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(20));  

This is best way, type-cast from TimeStamp to Date format.
Other simple solution are:
select
   CAST(TO_DATE(CAST(NOW() AS timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS VARCHAR(20)) as sol_2,
   TO_CHAR(CAST(NOW() AS timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as sol_3;

YelloBrick Validation:

